# Thread pool to create set number of threads per second

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to call a method 10 times per second on separate threads using a thread pool.  What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need this because the method may take more than 0.1 second to run? Otherwise a single thread can repeatedly "call a method 10 times per second".

Comment: Is a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) what you want?

Comment: I'd say download an IDE and start coding.

Comment: Just wanted a high level answer for what to look into, thanks to everyone that gave legit answers

Answer (score 2):

> call a method 10 times per second on separate threads using a thread
>   pool

**Define that method**

Let's suppose that the method you want to execute is the `myMethod()` of `MyClass` class, as shown bellow.

```
class MyClass{
 static void myMethod(){
   // some task
 }
}
```

**Define a** `Runnable` **that executes that method 10 times per second**

```
Runnable runnable = () ->{
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   try{
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     MyClass.myMethod();
   }catch{}
  }
};
```

**Initialize the thread pool**

```
int threadCount = 10; //whatever number of threads you wish
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```

**Start execution**

```
executor.execute(runnable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Executor Framework to maintain the thread(you can use Fixed Thread Pool) and call the method parallel using these thread.

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

executor.submit(task);

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 10 parallel threads use an `ExecutorService` with a fixed thread pool.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-

If you want to have something done every second you will need to look at using a scheduled thread pool.

It is not clear what you actually need.

Comment: How does that *"call a method 10 times per second"*?

Comment: Well it is not clear what the op wants. He said he wants to invoke the method from a pool of separate threads. The 10 per second part is ambiguous.

Comment: Which part of *"I want to call a method 10 times per second"* is ambiguous?

Comment: The same thing you yourself are asking in the comment to the question. Is it 10 per second in parallel? Is it 10 per second on each thread? In both cases my answer can be used if it is 10 per second on separate threads each thread can just sleep for 1 second, assuming each method call is very short. Otherwise the thread would call the method 10 times and sleep between each.